# I can't update state when submitted in a form

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to update the state on main page, the problem is that I update values 3 levels down...

This component is where I get all the cities, putting the data on the State and map through cities.

*CitiesPage.tsx*

```
export const CitiesPage = () => {
  const [cities, setCities] = useState<City[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCities().then(setCities);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <PageTitle title="Cities" />
      <StyledCitySection>
        <div className="headings">
          <p>Name</p>
          <p>Iso Code</p>
          <p>Country</p>
          <span style={{ width: "50px" }}></span>
        </div>
        <div className="cities">
          {cities.map((city) => {
            return <CityCard key={city.id} city={city} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </StyledCitySection>
    </>
  );
};
```

On the next component, I show cities and options to show modals for delete and update.

*CityCard.tsx*.

```
export const CityCard = ({ city }: CityProps) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const handleModal = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {showModal && (
        <ModalPortal onClose={handleClose}>
          <EditCityForm city={city} closeModal={setShowModal} />
        </ModalPortal>
      )}
      <StyledCityCard>
        <p className="name">{city.name}</p>
        <p className="isoCode">{city.isoCode}</p>
        <p className="country">{city.country?.name}</p>
        <div className="options">
          <span className="edit">
            <FiEdit size={18} onClick={handleModal} />
          </span>
          <span className="delete">
            <AiOutlineDelete size={20} />
          </span>
        </div>
      </StyledCityCard>
    </>
  );
};
```

and finally, third levels down, I have this component.

*EditCityForm.tsx*.

```
export const EditCityForm = ({ city, closeModal }: Props) => {
  const [updateCity, setUpdateCity] = useState<UpdateCity>({
    countryId: "",
    isoCode: "",
    name: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (
    evt: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    const { target } = evt;
    setUpdateCity({ ...updateCity, [target.name]: target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (evt: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const { id: cityId } = city;
    updateCityHelper(cityId, updateCity);
    closeModal(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setUpdateCity({
      isoCode: city.isoCode,
      name: city.name,
      countryId: city.country?.id,
    });
  }, [city]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Input
        label="Iso Code"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type a IsoCode..."
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="isoCode"
        value={updateCity.isoCode}
      />
      <Input
        label="Name"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Paste a Name.."
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="name"
        value={updateCity.name}
      />
      <CountrySelect
        label="Country"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={city.country?.name || ""}
        name="countryId"
      />
      <Button type="submit" color="green" text="Update" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Edit form where retrieve data passed from *CityCard.tsx* and update State, passing data to a function that update Info, closed modal and... this is where I don't know what to do.

How can I show the info updated on *CitiesPage.tsx* when I submitted on *EditCityForm.tsx*

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the updated value in a different state, namely the `updateCity` state, but what you should be doing is update the origional `cities` state. While these two states are not related, and at the same time your UI is depend on `cities` state's data, so if you wish to update UI, what you need to do is update `cities`' state by using it's setter function `setCities`.

Just like passing down state, you pass it's setters as well, and use the setter function to update state's value:

```
// CitiesPage
{cities.map((city) => {
    return <CityCard key={city.id} city={city} setCities={setCities} />;
})}

// CityCard
export const CityCard = ({ city, setCities }: CityProps) => {
    // ...

    return (
        // ...
        <ModalPortal onClose={handleClose}>
          <EditCityForm city={city} closeModal={setShowModal} setCities={setCities} />
        </ModalPortal>
        // ...
    )
}


// EditCityForm
export const EditCityForm = ({ city, closeModal, setCities }: Props) => {
  // const [updateCity, setUpdateCity] = useState<UpdateCity>({  // no need for this
  //   countryId: "",
  //   isoCode: "",
  //   name: "",
  // });  

  const handleSubmit = (evt: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const { id: cityId } = city;
    setCities(); // your update logic
    closeModal(false);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to use React-Redux or Context API whenever you have nested structures and want to access data throughout your app.

However in this case you can pass `setCities` and `cities` as a prop to `CityCard` and then pass this same prop in the `EditCityForm` component and you can do something like this in your handleSubmit.

```
const handleSubmit = (evt: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let updatedCities = [...cities];
    updatedCities.forEach(el => {
       if(el.id == updateCity.id) {
         el.countryCode = updateCity.countryCode;
         el.name = updateCity.name;
         el.isoCode = updateCity.isoCode;
       }
    })
    setCities(updatedCities);
    closeModal(false);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach, but the only way to add new cities is pass one city to the use-case *updateCityHelper(cityId, updateCity)*. You proposed me to pass entire array of cities like if storage was localy. Thanks anyway!